# Rails: Server side Google Analytics all trafic in 'Direct' source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics, server-side

I tried several gems for use Server Side GA.

=> Stacato

=> Gabba

=> ...

But I have always the same problem, in google analytics the SOURCE of all my events are in "Direct" (direct traffic), even if i use utm_source, ...

I remarked, each time I trigger an event, Google analytics create a new session with source "Direct" (and a location in United states), and I think the event is attributed to this session and no to my effective session.

[image]

[image]

My config (with the gem Gem Gabba https://github.com/hybridgroup/gabba ):

View application.html.erb

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
  </script>
```

Model User

```
Gabba::Gabba.new("UA-XXXXXX-1", "mysite.com").event('User', 'Signup', 'Profile completed')
```

I have a doubt if it's a configuration problem or if it's a recurrent problem when you use a Server Side GA?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ds

Comment: I know nothing about Rails, but quite a bit about GA and seeing that the gabba pages talks about "utmz cookies" and "custom vars" I would say that it hasn't been updated to work with universal analytics. You really shouldn't use this. Follow RaV's advice and either send directly via the measurement protocol, or look for a gem that supports it.

Comment: Thx you help me to find the answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thx @eike & @RaV, you help me to find a solution.

I removed the `gabba` gem and added `staccato` gem instead.
The problem was the same (`staccato` generated a new `client_id` by default, that's why I had a duplicate), but I figured out how to fix it.

1.Just save the `client_id` from in the google analytics cookie in your  application controller:

```
before_action :tacking_ga


def client_id
  cookies["_ga"].split(".").last(2).join(".")
end

  private

  def tacking_ga
    @tracker = Staccato.tracker('UA-XXXXXXXXX-1', client_id, ssl: true) if Rails.env == "production"
  end
```

2.After that in my controller (example `user_controller`) I just had to add my event at the right place:

```
@tracker.event(category: 'User', action: 'Signup', label: "Profile completed", value: nil)
```

Thx for your help